# PHP: csv generator creates extra field

Tags: php, file, csv

I'm coding a script that takes one csv file to transform it into another one. Basically, two foreach loops are used: one to iterate records and another to iterate fields. Certain fields (cno 25, 26, 44) for each record needs to be modified. The problem is that each modificatino creates an extra empty field, i.e. the code

```
$colStr .= '"' . $col . '";';
```

works but not any of the code in the if statements.

The code is:

```
$rno = 0;
foreach ($csvArray as $line)
{
 $cno = 0;
 $colStr = "";

 foreach ($line as $col)
 {

  if($rno>0 && $cno==25)
  {
   $stuff = array($csvArray[$rno][41], $csvArray[$rno][47], $csvArray[$rno][48], $csvArray[$rno][49]);


   foreach($stuff as &$value)
   {
    $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
   }
   sort($stuff, SORT_NUMERIC);

   // Causes bug!
   $colStr .= '"' . $stuff[0] . '";';
  }

  if($rno>0 && $cno==26)
  {
   $urls = "";

   for($i = 55; $i<=62; $i++)
   {
    $urls .= "Images: " . $csvArray[$rno][$i] . " | ";
   }
   $urls .= "Some text: " . $csvArray[$rno][43] . " | ";

   // Causes bug!
   $colStr .= '"' . $urls . '";';
  }

  if($rno>0 && $cno==44)
  {
   $colStr .= '"' . $_POST['location'][$rno] . '";';
  }

  if($rno>0 && $cno==54)
  {
   $objType = $col;

   $objType = preg_replace('/foobar/i', '123', $objType);

   // Causes bug!
   $colStr .= '"' . $objType . '";';
  }

  else
  {
   // This is ok, though
   $colStr .= '"' . $col . '";';
  }

  $cno++;
 }

 $colStr = preg_replace('/;$/', '', $colStr);
 $colStr .= "\n";
 fwrite($outputFile, $colStr);
 $rno++;

}

fclose($outputFile);
```

Comment: give a couple sample lines from the input and the output.  Are you adding in extra delimiters somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, just realized the if/else logic was messed up :( damnit.